# Delta live tables feature missing

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

In my Azure Databricks workspace UI I do not have the tab "Delta live tables". In the documentation is says that there is a tab after clicking on Jobs in the main menu.

Answer (score 1):

Delta Live Tables (DLT) is the first ETL framework that uses a simple declarative approach to building reliable data pipelines and automatically managing your infrastructure at scale so data analysts and engineers can spend less time on tooling and focus on getting value from data. With DLT, engineers are able to treat their data as code and apply modern software engineering best practices like testing, error handling, monitoring and documentation to deploy reliable pipelines at scale.

[image]

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Delta live tables is a Databricks Premium feature so it is only available in a premium workspace. More details about the features in each tier can be found [here](https://databricks.com/product/azure-pricing)